# Count nodes with specific number of children in a binary tree?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, nodes, children

I have this challenging exercise I got from a book about c++, and i'm not sure how to tackle this problem.
I must define a function called `treeNodeCount()` which returns the number of nodes in a binary tree (easy enough), and I also have to define an overloaded function that takes an int(0,1, or 2) which represents the number of children, and the function should return the nodes that have that specific number of children.
`treeNodeCount` should both use a function called `nodeCount(elemType root)` to do the recursion necessary to count the nodes(so basically all the work).

challenge number one says that I can add a second parameter to `nodeCount` which takes the number of children for the nodes that we want to count.

Challenge number two says that we cannot use a second parameter (this is the tough part)

I was able to do challenge one and here is what I came up with:

```
template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::nodeCount(nodeType<elemType> *p, int a ) const
{

    if (p == NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    else if (a == 0 && p->lLink == NULL && p->rLink == NULL){
        return 1 + nodeCount(p->lLink, a) + nodeCount(p->rLink, a);
    }
    else if (a == 1 && (p->lLink != NULL ^ p->rLink != NULL)){
        return 1 + nodeCount(p->lLink, a) + nodeCount(p->rLink, a);
    }
    else if (a == 2 && p->lLink != NULL && p->rLink != NULL){
        return 1 + nodeCount(p->lLink, a) + nodeCount(p->rLink, a);
    }

    else if (a == -1){
        return nodeCount(p->lLink, a) + nodeCount(p->rLink, a) + 1;

}
    return nodeCount(p->lLink, a) + nodeCount(p->rLink, a);
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::treeNodeCount(int a) const{
    return nodeCount(root, a);
}
```

This seems to work fine but i am convinced that there has to be a better way.
I was not able to do challenge 2 though, and i have no idea what to do (is it even possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scrunch down your logic and make it a bit more straightforward by implementing a function to return the number of children given a node.

```
template <class elemType>
int nodeSize(nodeType<elemType>* node) const
{
    int count = 0;
    if (node->lLink)
        ++count;
    if (node->rLink)
        ++count;
    return count;
}

template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::nodeCount(nodeType<elemType>* node, int count) const
{
    if (node)
    {
        if (nodeSize(node) == count || count == -1)
             return nodeCount(node->lLink, count) + nodeCount(node->rLink, count) + 1;
        return nodeCount(node->lLink, count) + nodeCount(node->rLink, count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For the second challenge, you need a stack to avoid recursion.

```
template <class elemType>
int binaryTreeType<elemType>::treeNodeCount(int count) const
{
    stack<nodeType<elemType>*> node_stack;
    node_stack.push(root);

    int num_matches = 0;
    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        nodeType<elemType>* node = node_stack.top();
        node_stack.pop();
        if (node)
        {
            if (nodeSize(node) == count || count == -1)
                ++num_matches;
            node_stack.push(node->lLink);
            node_stack.push(node->rLink);
        }
    }
    return num_matches;
}
```

*Edit: fixed a goof in the above recursive version. Thanks to David Rodriguez for pointing it out.*

Comment: The implementation of `nodeCount` does not have a stop condition for the recursion. There are a few dereferences of a pointer that may be null at this point.

Comment: Can the tree be empty? In that case you are still left with the same issue in the non-recursive case: `node_stack.push(root)` (possibly null) followed by `node = node_stack.top();... if (node->lLink)...` That last check makes sure that no null pointers are inserted into the stack, but the test is not evaluated for the root node.

Comment: You're right! I find it quite tricky to see all these edge cases just typing the code in without a compiler or test process. Will correct that as well!

Comment: I exchanged it for a version that checks post for null, creating deeper stacks than necessary in exchange for simpler code, but hope that's all right. I find it hard enough to write such exemplary code correctly without concerning myself with optimization, and technically `nodeSize` itself is rather inefficient with the extra branching.

Comment: The only change you needed in the previous version was to check for an empty tree (`if (!root) return 0;` as the first statement). The rest of the cases where covered by checking for null before pushing to the stack.

Comment: Yeah, I was tripping a bit since I was trying to make the stack and recursive versions somewhat symmetric to each other to try to make them easier to understand, but I got a bit indecisive in the middle. I settled just for a post-null check for both versions.

Comment: Also I have some bad paranoia habits I've developed where I want to optimize for the static branch predictor, so I'm used to forcefully writing the if check for the common case rather than the rare case, swinging me towards wanting to do if (root) as opposed to not if (!root), but then it all kind of lead to a 'whatever' mentality where I just decided to do it all post and push nulls to the stack. Apologies -- first time using this site and still struggling to make up my mind about how to write the code -- and also spotting mistakes in what I write.